# R foreach error when using formula notation in randomForest

Tags: r, foreach, random-forest

I have an issue running a randomForest in parrallel using fore each.
See this example, I create some data,then a formula notation.
The formula works on a randomForest by itself.
But fails when used in a foreach parrallel loop...?

```
# rf on big training set
# use parallel foreach
library(foreach)

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(4)  #change the 2 to your number of CPU cores 
# info on parrallell backend
getDoParName()
getDoParWorkers()

# bogus data
set.seed(123)
ssize <- 100000
x1 <- sample( LETTERS[1:9], ssize, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.05,0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05,0.1) )
x2 <- rlnorm(ssize,0,0.25)
x3 <- rlnorm(ssize,0,0.5)
y <- sample( c("Y","N"), ssize, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.05, 0.95))
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
df$p_y <- as.numeric(df$y)-1

# use strata to sample whole dataset
library(sampling)

s1 = strata(df,stratanames = "y", size = c(2500,2500))
s2 = strata(df,stratanames = "y", size = c(2500,2500))
s3 = strata(df,stratanames = "y", size = c(2500,2500))
s4 = strata(df,stratanames = "y", size = c(2500,2500))

s_list <- list(s1$ID_unit, s2$ID_unit, s3$ID_unit, s4$ID_unit)

# model function
rf.formula <- as.formula(paste("y","~",paste("x1","x2",sep="+")))

library(randomForest)

# simple stuff works but takes some time
model.rf <-randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50)

# build rf with dopar on explicit formula works and is quick
model.rf.dopar <- foreach(subset=s_list, .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
  randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)

# build rf with dopar on rf.formula fails
model.rf.s.b2 <- foreach(subset=s_list, .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
  randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)

# > model.rf.s.b2 <- foreach(subset=s_list, .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
#   +   randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)
# Error in randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree = 100, nodesize = 50, subset = subset) : 
#   task 1 failed - "invalid subscript type 'closure'"
```

The error:

```
model.rf.s.b2 <- foreach(subset=s_list, .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
   +   randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)

Error in randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree = 100, nodesize = 50, subset = subset) : 
task 1 failed - "invalid subscript type 'closure'"
```

Any suggestions?

Tx

Comment: Somethings going wrong with your subsetting. Try adding `print(subset)` or something along those lines within the `foreach` loop to see if it is in the format you're expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to an indexing operation going wrong deep down in the `model.frame.default` function, which is indirectly called by `randomForest.formula`.  I'm not at all sure what is triggering the problem because there are a lot of tricky evals happening in `model.frame.default`, but modifying the environment of the formula seems to fix the problem:

```
r <- foreach(subset=s_list, .combine='combine', .multicombine=TRUE,
             .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
  environment(rf.formula) <- environment()
  randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)
}
```

In particular, this causes `subset` to be evaluated correctly, otherwise it evaluates to the `subset` function.  I tried renaming the iteration variable, but it didn't help.

Note that I also set `.multicombine` to `TRUE` since the randomForest `combine` function accepts multiple objects, and that can improve performance significantly.

**Update**

The problem can be reproduced with:

```
fun <- function(subset) {
  randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=subset)
}
fun(s_list[[1]])
```

If the variable `subset` is changed to `s`, for example, it also fails, but with a less misleading error message:

```
> fun <- function(s) {
>   randomForest(rf.formula, df, ntree=100, nodesize = 50, subset=s)
> }
> fun(s_list[[1]])
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 's' not found
Calls: fun ... eval -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

As with the `foreach` example, resetting the environment of the formula seems to work-around the problem.

Comment: Excellent reply, thank you. Although this is a workaround it works for me.